# how to play other videos in html5

Tags: html

Hi i have this video tag html5 i use in the project. I have 5 videos on it, im wondering why other videos won't play so only one will play the videos. I want the five videos to be played. Here's my html5 code below

```
 <video id="bgvid" autoplay="autoplay"  loop="true">
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/video1.mp4" />
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/video2.mp4" />
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/shutterstock_v4192384.mov"  />
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/shutterstock_v4363250.mov" >
            </video>
```

only the first video will play the other's wont. the autolay works well and the loop also.
Can someone help me why it wont work?Any help is muchly appreciated.TIA

Comment: It seems you've misunderstood what `<source>` does. They're supposed to be different versions of the same video. If you want to play 5 different videos, you need 5 separate `<video>` tags.

Comment: hi @juhana ive tried your idea separate into 5 <video> tags what happened is the first video wont play goes directly to video2

Comment: Google for "html5 video playlist".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need separate video tags for each video.

```
<video id="bgvid1" autoplay loop="true">
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/video1.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video id="bgvid2" autoplay loop="true">
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/video2.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video id="bgvid3" autoplay loop="true">
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/shutterstock_v4192384.mov"  type="video/mov" />
</video>
<video id="bgvid4" autoplay loop="true">
                <source src="wp-content/uploads/videos/shutterstock_v4363250.mov"  type="video/mov" />
</video>
```

Comment: hi your codes seems not to work it jumps into the 3rd video

Comment: I've made a few edits. But I cannot help you much without the code you have written. You might want to recheck everything you've written to understand why the 3rd video plays.

Comment: its ok ive got no added script execept in the id which is a css codes on it ... ill try your edited code

Comment: ive tried your edited code  it seems to be the same jumps into 3rd video.. but have you tried that your code above? does that works?